# sqlite transaction during lengthy operation

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite, transactions

I'm building an app to make orders. When I add an item in the order, I remove the item quantity from stock. But if something goes wrong or the user cancel the order, I need to revert all the stock operations.
So, when I start a new order, I call beginTransaction(). Then I keep adding items. And when I'm done, I commit the transaction with setTransactionSuccessful() and endTransaction().

When inside a thread that started the transaction, I can 'see' the data I changed. In other hand, this data is not commited, so, not present if I run a query from another thread.

How can I get these changed data from another thread without commit my transaction?

I have thinking in make some kind of query serialization with a pool of queries inside a thread.

I'm in the right way?

Comment: don't try to synchronize using the sqlite database file, just use some shared objects

Comment: that would be one way. Another one would be to have a intermediary system, either a table or an in-memory object to hold the lines of your order, that you would put in the final table only at the end. A third one would be to do the opposite: save the data in the final table with a log object or table to be able to perform a rollback.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I solved my problem with a kind of "DatabaseManager", that can queue the queries and direct them to a consumer thread. Once only the thread that started the transactions can "touch" the fresh data, this approach have worked very well. Now, every time I'm in a transaction, every thread can access the new fresh data. If the transaction is canceled, the threads come back to the old data before the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

The context of a transaction is the database connection (`SQLiteDatabase` in Android).

To allow other threads to access the data changed in a transaction, you have to share the `SQLiteDatabase` object.
(Use the normal `synchronized` mechanism to manage concurrent accesses to that object.)